# Splitting values in columns based on symbol into new rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have pandas dataframe in this form:

```
A         B       C       D
car      100     EUR      T
train    20/r25  EUR/rUSD F
e-bike   10/r21  EUR/rGBP F
```

I want to split those columns on this `/r` symbol (thos columns that contain that symbol) so the other columns are duplicated as seen on result df:

Result df:

```
A         B       C   D
car      100     EUR  T
train    20      EUR  F
train    25      USD  F 
e-bike   10      EUR  F
e-bike   21      GBP  F
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create `Index` or `MultiIndex` by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with all columns which are not splitted, then [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) each column, convert `MultiIndex` to columns and add [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) for order of columns like in original and also for remove `level` columns:

```
df1 = (df.set_index(['A', 'D'])
        .apply(lambda x: x.str.split('/r', expand=True).stack())
        .reset_index()
        .reindex(df.columns, axis=1))
print (df1)
        A    B    C  D
0     car  100  EUR  T
1   train   20  EUR  F
2   train   25  USD  F
3  e-bike   10  EUR  F
4  e-bike   21  GBP  F
```

EDIT:

```
df1 = (df.set_index(['D','E', 'F','G'])
        .apply(lambda x: x.str.split('\r', expand=True).stack(dropna=False))
        .reset_index()
        .reindex(df.columns, axis=1)
        )
print (df1)
           A           B    C                           D             E  \
0      NUMER        DATA  WAL  OKRESY WIEKOWANIA W DNIACH           NaN   
1  DOKUMENTU    OPERACJI  UTA  OKRESY WIEKOWANIA W DNIACH           NaN   
2        NaN         NaN  NaN                       do 90  od 91 do 180   
3        NaN         NaN  NaN                       do 90  od 91 do 180   
4        NaN  2015-03-09  EUR                         NaN           NaN   
5        NaN        None  PLN                         NaN           NaN   
6        NaN  2015-12-07  EUR                         NaN           NaN   
7        NaN        None  PLN                         NaN           NaN   

               F              G         H  
0            NaN            NaN       NaN  
1            NaN            NaN       NaN  
2  od 181 do 270  od 271 do 360    od 361  
3  od 181 do 270  od 271 do 360      None  
4            NaN            NaN     10,56  
5            NaN            NaN     43,60  
6            NaN            NaN  1 368,24  
7            NaN            NaN  5 902,72
```

Comment: How about multiple columns? So that should not be setting 'A' as index I think? I updated the question.

Comment: I'm getting error: `Cannot handle non-unique multi-index`

Comment: @AlexT - Can you check `df1 = (df.reset_index(drop=True)
         .set_index(['A', 'D'])
         .apply(lambda x: x.str.split('/r', expand=True).stack())
         .reset_index()
         .reindex(df.columns, axis=1))
print (df1)` ?

Comment: @AlexT - Is possible some missng values? then maybe `stack()` changed to `.stack(dropna=False)` should help

Comment: @AlexT - Problem in real data?

Comment: Yes I can send sample from real dataset

Comment: @AlexT - Super, please send to my email in my profile

Comment: Thank you, I send you the link to file

Comment: @AlexT - Answer was edited, but no error in data for me :(